# Horse Racing Odds in Statistics

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a math project to do in statistics and probability. I am given a table of data related to horse racing biding which contain Odds of a Favorite Winning, if the favorite won etc.

So I have 300 races and the bookies odds of the favorite winning right, they are in form of:

1. 4/1
2. 9/4
3. 7/4
4. 11/4
5. 9/4

So now I have the following question:

- 1) Calculate the average odds of favorite winning.
- 2) What is the probability of a favorite winning.

I can't seem to understand how to calculate the 1st question. My approach was to add up the Odds like so: (in the given 5 samples)

4/1+

9/4+

7/4+

11/4+

9/4=

............

40/17

which I divide both side by 5 (since there are 5 races in this sample), thus the average odds of the given samples is 8/3.4 (rounded up gives 8/3). Is that correct? I was told if you convert the odds to probability and then add up the mum of them and then divide by number of races you will get a skewed result. And correct me if I'm wrong but calculating the odds is for example -> given 11/4, the odds of happening are 11/(4+11) = 0.73 == 73%

Now for the 2nd question what I simply did is I took the number of wins and divided that by number of races which is basically relative frequency approach.. P(E) = # of desired outcomes / # of repetitions of the experiment.. which in this case relates to P(E) = # of wins / # of races, isn't that correct?

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is basically sound but I think you are confusing odds with probabilities.

Odds of 4:1 means that the book maker is prepared to give you £4 if the horse wins provided you give him £1 if it doesn't.  Typically the book maker will take your £1 up front and return it to you together with the £4 (making £5 in total) if you win but it can be just an agreement with no money changing hands until the result is known.

This means the horse has a $\frac{1}{5}$ chance of winning. So no looking at probabilities instead

$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
Odds & Probability \\
\hline
4 : 1 & \frac{1}{5} \\
9 : 4 & \frac{4}{13} \\
7 : 4 & \frac{4}{11} \\
11: 4 & \frac{4}{15} \\
9 : 4 & \frac{4}{13} \\ 
\end{array}
$$

Adding these up and dividing by 5 the average probability of a horse winning is $\frac{3101}{10725}$ making the odds 7620 : 3101

Also note the odds do not directly represent the real chances of horse winning but a perceived chance and the odds may go up or down depending on how much money has been bet.

So the real probaility of the favourite winning are just

$$
\frac{\text{The number of races won by the favourite}}{\text{total number of races}}
$$

Comment: So basically rounded a/1 this would be 2/1 right?

Comment: Actually 2.457:1 so 2:1 would be the nearest.

Comment: Well the "real" probability is really unknown. What you give is the empirical probability, which may contain realizations of luck etc. Also, I thought probabilities based on bookmaker odds do not sum to 1 (fees). Shouldn't there be some normalization?

Comment: Why would you not take the average odds and then invert them to give the probability of the horse winning?